# Assert that a specific exception is thrown in a Kafka listener method

Tags: java, exception, junit

I have a `@KafkaListener` method that might throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. For the sake of the question it might look like:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "SomeTopic")
public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, SomeDto> record) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Whats up?");
}
```

As part of integration testing (using Spring Boot and JUnit) I want to test the method and assert that an exception has indeed been thrown. In my test class, I have a test that boils down to:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exceptionRule = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void createHierarchy_invalidEventType_exception() {
    exceptionRule.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class);
    kafkaTemplate.send("SomeTopic", someDto);
}
```

The log shows:

> org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.something.EventService.listenPosition(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord)' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This event type is not supported.;

So `IllegalArgumentException` got wrapped into `ListenerExecutionFailedException` and I modified my test method:

```
@Test
public void createHierarchy_invalidEventType_exception() {
    exceptionRule.expectCause(isA(IllegalArgumentException.class));
    kafkaTemplate.send("SomeTopic", someDto);
}
```

But the log still shows the same stack trace. What am I doing wrong? How do I verify that the `@KafkaListener` method  indeed threw the exception?

**EDIT:**
Here's the test's stack trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected test to throw (an instance of org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException and exception with cause is an instance of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)

    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.failDueToMissingException(ExpectedException.java:263)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.access$200(ExpectedException.java:106)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:245)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Thanks.

Comment: is there a change to catch `ListenerExecutionFailedException` ?

Comment: Deadpool, I've tried. `exceptionRule.expect(ListenerExecutionFailedException.class);` doesn't change a thing. The stack trace remains the same and the test fails.

Comment: are these spring boot integration test or just `junit `test ?

Comment: Deadpool, added to the question - integration testing with Spring Boot.

Comment: Can't you just get the exception from the method invocation and use Spring's [NestedExceptionUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/NestedExceptionUtils.html) to get the root cause which is `IllegalArgumentException` and do the assertion against that?